# How can I resolve Oracle 11g XE connection failure straight after installation?

Tags: windows-7, oracle, virtualbox, oracle-11g, oraclexe

I have just installed Oracle 11g XE on a Windows 7 VirtualBox VM, using all the default options.

**"Getting Started" fails**

When I click on *Getting Started* I get taken to  http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 which fails. After some browsing I came across a suggestion to confirm the HTTP port, but I can't get this far, because I can't connect.

**`connect system` fails**

If I select *Run SQL command line* I get taken to a SQL prompt. I enter `connect system` and get prompted for a password. I enter the password. I immediately get the following error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

**Info: Start database**

This happens whether or not I run *Start database* first. (*Start database* just opens a Windows command prompt window.)

**Info: Windows services**

My Oracle services start as follows:

[image: Oracle XE services default startup]

Starting the manual services doesn't resolve the problem. Enabling and starting the disabled service doesn't resolve the problem.

Is there something I haven't done? How can I resolve this connection error?

Comment: Is Oracle Services working. Use net start command or services.msc to control.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur thanks for the tip, I've added services info above, starting the unstarted services didn't resolve the issue however :(

Comment: try to login using sqlplus "/as sysdba"

Comment: # Hi,
I am also getting the same issue pop up(The installer is unable to instantiate the file C:\Users\SAMRAT\AppData\Local\Temp\{some value..}\KEY_XE.reg), so according to this blog I went to the path mentioned in the error pop up but could not find out the file “KEY_XE.reg” where I will set up the key data value.I am also installing in Windows7 64 bit.The DB installation file is “OracleXE112_Win32″.Please help me in resolving this issue.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each and every unexpected behaviour/error see the installation logs at **C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\config\log**. It will tell what went wrongs during notifications.

In my case, it shows some thing related to windows events are full. I cleared all the events, de-install oracle and re-install. Everything is perfect.

Comment: I'm accepting this untested because I ended up creating another VM and the second time it worked; it's a helpful answer nonetheless, and at least a source of more info should someone else run into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The following seemed to work for me.

Open a browser and navigate to the below url, this should get you where you need to go:

```
http://[localhost]:8080/apex/f?p=4950
```

Actual port number (8080) may be different in your installation.

Taken from here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9542052.

Comment: my original problem was that the URL failed; are you suggesting using the machine name and/or `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`?